# See if page has been server over https or not in app engine

Tags: https, log-files, google-app-engine

As Google App Engine rolled out the [inclusion of Let's Encrypt certificate](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900034), I am *now* able to serve my site over **https**.

I did not find how to make a proper redirect from *http* to *https*, so I made it at the application level (in *python*) by calling a redirect if the page is accessed over *http*.

I would like to know, now, if all the pages are served over *https*. From looking at the log, I can see no indication whether there are served or not over *https*. Is there a way to display that ?

I wouldn't want to log every *https* request, just to see that. May be a lighter thing like tags ?

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to finally offer https service always, by automatically redirecting http requests to the HTTPS URL, you can set the "secure" parameter in the app.yaml configuration file to the "always" value. This is documented in the "handlers element" sub-chapter of the "app.yaml Reference" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref).

Optionally, you can set the "redirect_http_response_code" as well, and use the set value to determine if all pages are served over https; this is what you actually would like to know at this stage.